# Generate a series of months within a period

Tags: postgresql, datetime

I want to generate a series of months within a specific time period.

I have tried:

```
select  GENERATE_SERIES( '06/25/2016'::DATE, '12/15/2016'::DATE, '1 month' )
```

It returns:

```
"generate_series"
"2016-06-25 00:00:00-06"
"2016-07-25 00:00:00-06"
"2016-08-25 00:00:00-06"
"2016-09-25 00:00:00-06"
"2016-10-25 00:00:00-06"
"2016-11-25 00:00:00-07"
```

There is an issue at the end date. I want the result as follows:

```
"generate_series"
 "2016-06-25 00:00:00-06"
 "2016-07-25 00:00:00-06"
 "2016-08-25 00:00:00-06"
 "2016-09-25 00:00:00-06"
 "2016-10-25 00:00:00-06"
 "2016-11-25 00:00:00-07"
 "2016-12-15 00:00:00-07"
```

I am using PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Evan explains why the `generate_series()` cannot do by itself what you want. But it can be done with a simple `UNION`:

```
select generate_series('2016-06-25'::timestamp, '2016-12-15', '1 month') 
         as g_date 
union 
select '2016-12-15'
-- order by g_date 
;
```

or `UNION ALL`:

```
select generate_series('2016-06-25'::timestamp, 
                       '2016-12-15' - interval '1 day', 
                       '1 month') as g_date 
union all
select '2016-12-15' ;
```

Also note that `generate_series()` output is of `timestamp without
timezone` type. if you want a `date` type, you need to cast:

```
select generate_series('2016-06-25'::timestamp, 
                       '2016-12-15' - interval '1 day', 
                       '1 month')::date as g_date 
union all
select '2016-12-15'::date ;
```

Answer (score 4):

The function you're calling has a signature of `generate_series(start, stop, step interval)`. Because of this it can never generate a data point after the `stop` argument. It stops. So for sanity, because you want the 25th day of the month, what you need is for

1. *stop* to be hard-coded after the 25th, such as the end of month

   ```
   SELECT ts
   FROM generate_series(
     '06/25/2016'::DATE,
     '12/31/2016'::DATE,
     '1 month'
   ) AS t(ts);
   ```
2. *start* and *stop* to be the first month, and then you just add 24 days to get the 25th day.

   ```
   SELECT ts + '24 days'
   FROM generate_series(
     '06/1/2016'::DATE,
     '12/1/2016'::DATE,
     '1 month'
   ) AS t(ts);
   ```
3. To calculate a stop point after the 25th day... such as this method.. calculates last day of the month.

   ```
   SELECT ts
   FROM generate_series(
     '06/25/2016'::DATE,
     (date_trunc('month', '12/15/2016'::date) + '1 month - 1 day')::DATE,
     '1 month'
   ) AS t(ts);
   ```